# Is there anyway to have a include a script for the entire WSF file?

Tags: wcf, windows-scripting, wsh

I was introduced to wsf today and now I have to write some code in it as well.

I get the concept of "job" and appreciate the flexibility of "script".

What I am confused about is that if I want to use an external JavaScript file in more than one job then I have to include it in each job.

Is there a way to do this globally for the whole file?

I am looking into WCF as well, but it seems that even if I build the component I still have to include it in each job individually.

Any help or workaround would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<job id="CreateLogFile">

<script language="JScript" src="IncludeFile.js"/>
...
</job>
```

Are you looking for something like this?

Comment: Sorry but I think this would be specific to one job not all jobs in the script.